# An Easter Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, seasonal

I woke up this morning to find Easter eggs hidden around the house.  Instead of being filled with chocolate, each one had a slip of paper inside.  Apparently the Easter Bunny left a puzzle to solve.  What does it all mean?  (Each line represents one clue inside an egg.  They are listed in the order they were found.)

- 8.Need more than one meaning for this to be solved
- 6.A tricky puzzle to stretch your mind
- 3.Wish for answers and watch for signs
- 2.Ask me my name, I'm the Easter Bunny!
- 4.The riddle I've hidden is split into lines
- 1.I'm fluffy and furry and a little bit funny
- 5.Arrange them properly and you will find
- 7.Here's a conundrum: the numbers involved

On the other side of each these were some random letters and numbers.

- 2.FYY
- 8.QW
- 6.MC
- 7.FM
- 5.DMT
- 4.PKZ
- 1.VEB
- 3.XSK

Comment: Are the "random letters and numbers" also listed in the order they were found (i.e. FYY goes with "Need more than one ...", QW goes with "A tricky puzzle ...", and so on)?

Comment: @randal'thor Yes, the letters and numbers are also listed in the order they were found

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Focusing on the numbers of the lines on the front side of the papers, I suppose we should see this:

> 8.Need mor**e** than one meaning for this to be solved
>  6.A tric**k**y puzzle to stretch your mind
>  3.Wi**s**h for answers and watch for signs
>  2.A**s**k me my name, I'm the Easter Bunny!
>  4.The **r**iddle I've hidden is split into lines
>  1.**I**'m fluffy and furry and a little bit funny
>  5.Arra**n**ge them properly and you will find
>  7.Here's a **c**onundrum: the numbers involved

Putting the letters in a line we get:

> ekssrinc

Rearranging them to solve the anagram we get the **answer**:

> Snickers

Presuming that all the numbers given must have some use, so this must be the second meaning of the numbers involved.

Comment: @rand al'thor Thanks for the formatting.

Comment: Correct!  Combined with the decoded question, this is the answer to the puzzle.

Answer (score 10):

Let's put those lines in order. There shouldn't be anything special about the order they're listed in in the question, because you said that was just "the order they were found" around the house.

1. I'm fluffy and furry and a little bit funny
2. Ask me my name, I'm the Easter Bunny!
3. Wish for answers and watch for signs
4. The riddle I've hidden is split into lines
5. Arrange them properly and you will find
6. A tricky puzzle to stretch your mind
7. Here's a conundrum: the numbers involved
8. Need more than one meaning for this to be solved

And the letters and numbers from the other side, in the same rearranged order:

4.PKZ
7.FM
6.MC
5.DMT
1.VEB
8.QW
3.XSK
2.FYY

Let's try

> Caesar-shifting each of these lines by the number given on the left:
>
>  4.TOD
>  7.MT
>  6.SI
>  5.IRY
>  1.WFC
>  8.YE
>  3.AVN
>  2.HAA

Now we need to find the *second* "meaning [of] the numbers involved" in order to finish the puzzle. An obvious thing to try is to

> rearrange the strings of letters and numbers in the order of *these* numbers:
>
>  1.WFC
>  2.HAA
>  3.AVN
>  4.TOD
>  5.IRY
>  6.SI
>  7.MT
>  8.YE

Thanks to [Deusovi](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36745807#36745807), we can now

> read downwards instead of left-to-right,

to get the final solution:

> WHAT IS MY FAVO[U]RITE CANDY

The answer, presumably, is

> Easter eggs!

Comment: You're very close, the answer is hidden in the puzzle

Comment: The candy is probably chocolate, which is what the poster originally expected to find in the eggs. Presumably the Easter Bunny stole or kept the chocolate and gave you a puzzle instead.

Comment: @Silenus Hmm, I thought of that, but I assumed that an answer hidden somewhere in the puzzle would be concealed more subtly/cryptically.